# how to fix wp-admin to point on the subfolder's wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, redirect, subdirectory

umm, actually i already did the redirection stuff and its working fine
however what i'm having a problem is the /wp-admin page

To illustrate:

domain name: mysite.com 
subfolder name: mysite.com/wpfolder

*take note mysite.com has wordpress installed on it same as the wpfolder subfolder*

i successfully redirected the subfolder to act as the main site by following on this article
http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
so whenever i visit mysite.com it is actually viewing mysite.com/wpfolder but only showing mysite.com on the url.

but whenever i try to access wp-admin of the subfolder i need to go in this link
**mysite.com/wpfolder/wp-admin**

because if i try to put this way **mysite.com/wp-admin** it will go to the old site, i mean on the root.

How do i fix this one?
please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you need both Wordpress installs? Or are you just using the wpfolder as the main?

It wont work if you need both installs, because each one needs it's own admin backend...

Comment: so are you saying that i need to remove the old wordpress install? which is on the root folder?

Comment: If your root has your old site, you can remove it; if it's not needed. I'd suggest move your wpfolder files to your root directory, because it doesn't make any sense running it from a subfolder. You can try out this plugin to duplicate the wordpress in wpfolder and transfer it to the root http://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ It changes your url's for your site and home as well as your files such as uploads etc.